# Why does an empty tabularx throw an error?

Tags: tabularx

Why does an empty `tabularx` throw an error ? (by empty, I mean only space, no newline)

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c | c|}
\end{tabular}                                        % <-- Works

\begin{tabular}{|c | c|}\end{tabular}                % <-- Works

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c | c|}
\end{tabularx}                                        % <-- Works

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c | c|}\end{tabularx}   % <-- Does not work

\end{document}
```

(This is particulary frustrating with `\ExplSyntaxOn`)

Comment: "why" is probably that it didn't occur to me to test for this and trap it.

Comment: Well... I guess it's probably a good reason ^^'

Comment: This code has been available for almost 30 years and you are the first person to report this issue:-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"why" is probably that it didn't occur to me to test for this and trap it.

Looking at tracing all the reason is that in

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c | c|}\end{tabularx}
```

The entire body (that `tabularx` needs to grab as a macro argument) is `{|c | c|}` and tex silently drops brace groups that surround an entire delimited argument, so this is passed to `tabularx` as

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}|c | c|\end{tabularx}
```

and things go wrong.

If you are generating this and there is a chance it might be empty you could use the optional argument

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}[c]{|c | c|}\end{tabularx}   % <-- Does not work
```

works for example.

I can probably catch this in a future release.

---

possible fix

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\makeatletter
\def\foo#1{%
\def\tabularx##1{%
\edef\TX@{\@currenvir}%
  {\ifnum0=`}\fi
  \setlength\TX@target{##1}%
  \TX@typeout{Target width: ##1 = \the\TX@target}%
  \toks@{}\TX@get@body#1}}
\foo{ }
\makeatother
\begin{document}


\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c | c|}\end{tabularx}   % <-- Does not work

\end{document}
```

Comment: In my case, it's not that a big deal once i know it can't be empty. I actually encountered it when debugging a macro to generate table, and I stuck on this error not knowing that an empty tabularx would error

Comment: @hl037_ see update